# How to order the tpm() output in R?

Tags: r

```
> final3pl

Call:
  tpm(data = finalqnum, type = "latent.trait")

Coefficients:
  Gussng  Dffclt  Dscrmn
p01   0.000  -1.503   1.379
p02   0.000  -1.407   1.427
p03   0.000  -1.121   1.873
p04   0.058  -0.888   2.428
p05   0.009  -1.049   2.345
p06   0.149  -1.010   2.158
p07   0.261   0.906   1.771
p09   0.000  -2.000   1.151
p10   0.000  -0.754   1.069
q31   0.021  -0.066   1.164
q10   0.205   0.261   1.028
q11   0.132   1.268   1.078
q12   0.077  -0.112   1.116
q13   0.170   2.847   2.245
q15   0.205   1.155   2.218

Log.Lik: -6954.86
```

It seemed that output display order by item name.I would like to display by order Dffclt,Dscrmn.How to do?

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example?

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read [MCVE] to improve your questions and have a better chance of getting the help you seek!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum reproducible example:

```
library(ltm)
fit <- tpm(LSAT)
fit
# Call:
# tpm(data = LSAT)
# 
# Coefficients:
#         Gussng  Dffclt  Dscrmn
# Item 1   0.053  -3.422   0.785
# Item 2   0.003  -1.367   0.720
# Item 3   0.372   0.653  23.202
# Item 4   0.020  -1.919   0.648
# Item 5   0.023  -2.951   0.692
# 
# Log.Lik: -2467.431
```

Retrieve coefficients:

```
coefs <- ltm:::IRT.parm(fit)$parms
coefs[, 1] <- plogis(coefs[, 1]) * fit$max.guessing
```

Well, you're not really supposed to access unexported functions (with the three colons `:::`), but it works. How did I know to look there? I looked at the code for the `print` function: `ltm:::print.tpm`).

Then order:

```
coefs[order(coefs[, "Dffclt"], coefs[, "Dscrmn"]), ]
#            Gussng     Dffclt     Dscrmn
# Item 1 0.05304277 -3.4220211  0.7848064
# Item 5 0.02251662 -2.9508802  0.6917242
# Item 4 0.02022046 -1.9185162  0.6480624
# Item 2 0.00340421 -1.3671207  0.7196966
# Item 3 0.37248584  0.6531424 23.2015044
```

(Not really sure what you mean by "order Dffclt,Dscrmn" since `Dscrmn` won't be used for ordering unless you've got duplicate values of `Dffclt`)

Comment: Your answer is correct! and I notice a problem the Gussng value changed.for example, item1 from 0.052 to -2.88.what cause it?

Comment: Oh you're right, I missed this line of code in `print.tpm`: `coefs[, 1] <- plogis(coefs[, 1]) * x$max.guessing`. I'll edit my answer